# Find and extract all numbers from the String

Tags: c#, regex, string, numbers

I have a string like: "`Hello I'm 43 years old, I need 2 burgers each for 1.99$`".
I need to parse it and get all the numbers in it as `double`. So the function should return an array of values like: `43, 2, 1.99`. In C++ I should've write all by myself, but C# has `Regex` and I think it may be helpful here:

```
String subjectString = "Hello I'm 43 years old, I need 2 burgers each for 1.99$";
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\d+").Value;
double result = double.Parse(resultString);
```

After this, the `resultString` is "43" and `result` is `43.0`. How to parse the string to get more numbers?

Comment: As for me, this question has more complete answer, so make a decision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex needs to be a little more complex to include decimals:

```
\d+(\.\d+)?
```

Then you need to get multiple matches:

```
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(subjectString, "\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    double d = double.Parse(m.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

[Here is an example](http://ideone.com/nHczwB).

Comment: Be sure to check for locale issues if needed. Not everyone uses the same decimal separator.

Comment: @GaussZ you mean dot or comma?

Comment: @GaussZ Good point. Yes, could be dot or comma. Also perhaps you input also needs to take care of thousands separators?

Comment: @RomanChehowsky Yes. Also usually the 10^3 separator is the opposite (comma for dot-decimal-separators and vice versa).

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the following regular expression:

```
-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?
```

and then use `Regex.Matches` and iterate over the matches returned.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Matches` method to get a collection of matches. Also, you need to add dot to your regex

```
String subjectString = "Hello I'm 43 years old, I need 2 burgers each for 1.99$";
var matches = Regex.Matches(subjectString, @"\d+(\.\d+)?");

for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++ )
{
    double d = double.Parse(matches[i].Value);
}
```